# Can I build FireBreath NPAPI Plugin for DirectFB?

Tags: linux, npapi, firebreath, directfb

Is it possible to build NPAPI plugin using FireBreath for webkit browser running on directFB,  embedded linux?

I am asking because I found that while building a my test plugin on ubuntu, It is using below x11 related files,

```
[  6%] Building CXX object projects/mvp/PluginAuto/CMakeFiles/mvp_PluginAuto.dir/X11/NpapiPluginX11.cpp.o                                            
[  8%] Building CXX object projects/mvp/PluginAuto/CMakeFiles/mvp_PluginAuto.dir/X11/PluginWindowX11.cpp.o                                           
[ 10%] Building CXX object projects/mvp/PluginAuto/CMakeFiles/mvp_PluginAuto.dir/X11/np_x11main.cpp.o
```

Well I dont want to make a gui plugin, I am making a plugin by which we can control external media player from browser with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If DirectFB/webkit supports NPAPI plugins then I'm sure it's possible, however you may need to create a patch to FireBreath to support it.

DirectFB is not officially supported by FireBreath and the primary developer (that would be me) hasn't the slightest idea what DirectFB would require to do such a thing; if you can figure it out, I'd be happy to help you with where to look first on adding support.  I am on the IRC room during the day MST/MDT (GMT-0700/-0600). I missed you asking this question in there by about 5 hours.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I will contact you on IRC.

Comment: I need very basic plugin so I am planning to create it with raw NPAPI methods, but creating plugin with out reading articles http://colonelpanic.net/2009/03/building-a-firefox-plugin-part-one/ is impossible, thanks for this. You made my life a lot easy. :-)